# Ada - Days of the week

Tags: ada

I'm supposed to make a subprogram that has exactly one parameter of type Integer. And this Integer represents a day of the week where 1 is monday, 2 is tuesday etc...

The subprogram should return how many days there's left until Saturday.

This is my approach (I'm not supposed to use arrays):

```
with Ada.Text_IO;         use Ada.Text_IO;                          
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure Test3 is
    function Week (Days : in Integer) return Integer is
    begin
        if Days = 1 then
            return 5;
        elsif Days = 2 then
            return 4;
        elsif Days = 3 then
            return 3;
        elsif Days = 4 then
            return 2;
        elsif Days = 5 then
            return 1;
        elsif Days = 6 then
            return 7;
        elsif Days = 7 then
            return 6;
        end if; 
    end Week;
      
    Days : Integer;
    
begin
    Put("What day is it: ");
    Get(Days);

    if Days < 0 or Days > 7 then
        Put_Line("Wrong Value");
    end if;

    Put("It's ");
    Put(Week(Days), Width => 1);
    Put(" days until Saturday.");          
end Test3;
```

Even though my program works I have two problems. Do you see the amount of "elsifs", can this not be solved in any other way? I don't like how my program looks.

Secondly,

How am I supposed to make an if statement where if Days < 0 or Days > 7 will raise an error. As you can see I have attempted to this in my main program but it won't work since I have
"Get(Days);" before this statement and my subprogram won't recognize my if statement? Should I put my if statement in my subprogram instead?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your range of legal values is 0 .. 7, which covers 8 values! What integer value corresponds to Sunday? (0 or 7, you choose - unless the requirements say which). Your function `Week` should be called something like `Days_Til_Saturday` and should return Natural (0 would be the answer if it’s already Saturday). I don’t know who’s providing this question but They Are Not Using Ada Properly!

Comment: You are absolutely right. But even though I add this value it will still be a flawed program. My if statement in my subprogram will still look terrible and I don't think I can solve this with a loop. Also, where am I supposed to put the statement where Days < 0 or Days > 7 will raise an error

Comment: You might find keywords "mod" or "rem" are useful in eliminating the long IF statement.

Answer (score 1):

With respect to raising error, how about

```
  if Days not in 1 .. 7 then
     Put_Line("Wrong Value");
     raise Contrain_Error with "Days is out of range, " & Days'Image;
  else
     -- normal processing
  end if;
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the question of what to do with invalid Days, that is for you to decide, and then you code the subprogram accordingly. I think the most natural, for Ada, would be to put the check in the subprogram and raise Constraint_Error if it fails.

As Simon Wright said, you must decide and specify (and describe in comments) how the week-days are numbered. Otherwise no-one can check your code.

Once you have clearly decided and described those things, for yourself and for any reader of the program, you can have a closer look at your if-then-else nest and see how systematically the return value depends on the input value. Maybe there is a simple formula that can handle most cases, or perhaps all cases with valid input? That would let you reduce the number of if-then-elses.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you allow day numbers in 1 .. 7. You can state this directly

```
subtype Day_Number is Integer range 1 .. 7;

function Days_Till_Saturday (Day : in Day_Number) return Day_Number;
```

You can then omit the check on the input value; passing an invalid value to the function will raise `Constraint_Error`, which you can handle to report the error.

Regarding the long chain of `elsif`s, you can use a case statement:

```
case Day is
when 1 =>
   return 5;
```

but for this problem it might be clearer to use arithmetic:

```
   Result : constant Integer := 6 - Day;
begin
   if Result not in Day_Number then
      return Result + Day_Number'Last;
   end if;

   return Result;
```